# I am writing a code about replacing a word in a string with another word and removing repeats. Cannot finish it but got half to work

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//This function converts a string to a sentence.
void
StrtoSent(char *string)
{
    int length = 0,n = 0;
    length = strlen(string);
    for(n = 0;  n < length;  n++){
        if((n ==0) && (string[n] >= 'b' && string[n] <= 'y')){
            string[n] = string[n] - 32;
        }
        else if(string[n] == '.'){
            if(string[n + 1] == ' '){
                if(string[n+2]>= 'b' && string[n+2]<= 'y'){
                    string[n+2]= string[n+1] - 32;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    char string[50] = {0};
    int length = 0,n = 0,a = 0,d = 0;
    printf("\n\nEnter a wordstring Neo: ");
    gets(string);
    StrtoSent(string);//Here,we send the string off to the function
    char str[] = "The xitraM is acutally the Matrix!";
    char j[] = "xitraM";
    char e[] = "Matrix";
    char *result = NULL;
    printf("Original string: %s\n",str);
    printf("The converted sentence: %s",string);
    char input[200];
    getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(input,200,stdin);
    char c;
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        int n = c - '0'; //'0'-'9' -> 0 - 9
        printf("%c is coverted to %d\n",c,n);
    }
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        if(islower(c))
        printf("%c will be converted to %c\n",c,toupper(c));
        if(isupper(c))
        printf("%c in lowercase is %c\n",c,tolower(c));
        getchar();
    }

}
```

How do I replace the word `xitraM` and get it to be like this output:

```
The xirtaM is actually the MATRIX!
```

Converted sentence:

```
The Matrix is actually the MATRIX!
```

Original:

```
a blACk cAT is in the xirtaM.
```

Converted sentence:

```
A Black Cat is in the Matrix.
```

My code allows you
so far to enter a wordstring and it will return a string, and it will
fix the //code if there are capitals in the wrong place and if the
punctuation is wrong, but I cannot seem to get the code to replace
`xitraM` with `Matrix` and I am stuck on that.

Some help would be great -- thanks!

Comment: _Never_ do `fflush(stdin)`--it will just mess things up. _Never_ use `gets`--the man page says _don't_ use it. You're reading several lines at different places instead of a single `fgets` in a loop. And, I don't think you want to do `getchar` at all, since you've already read the input line.

Comment: The original string `xitraM` and the corrected string `Matrix` are set into variables in `main`, but you never do anything with them. For that conversion, you probably want _two_ buffers, one is the input and the second is the output. Then, you can use `strstr` on the input, looking for the `xitraM` string, copying over what precedes it, then copying `Matrix`--loop and repeat

Comment: the posted code is rather messy, with lots of 'unused' variables.

Comment: regarding: `char c;
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        int n = c - '0';`  The `char` `c` is not initialized at this point in the code.

Comment: regarding: `char c;` and `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`  1) The `getchar()` function returns a `int`, not a `char`.  2) depending on if a `char` is signed or unsigned in your compiler implementation, it may be unable to recognize a EOF.  Suggest changing `char c;` to `int c;`

Comment: regarding; `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)` and `getchar();` this results in two characters being read in each loop and one of those characters is discarded.  Suggest removing the 'stand alone' call to `getchar()`

Comment: @user3629249 Because OP does `fgets` [`gets`] to get the input line, using `getchar` [at all] is superfluous. The fixed code would just eliminate it altogether. More likely, this is misplaced capitalization code [that should just loop on the already read buffer].

Answer (score 1):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

There are many issues with the code.

*Never* use `gets`--the man page for it says to *not* use it [and why].

Your `main` is reading a line but not doing much with it.

The loop at the bottom doing `getchar` makes no sense because you've already read the line with the `fgets` above. It looks like you're trying to preview the capitalization.

For the word substitution, use *two* buffers. An input and a separate output buffer. Although `xirtaM` and `Matrix` are the same length, using separate buffers allows the length of the strings to differ (i.e. it's more general).

You can loop through the input using `strstr` to find the "bad" string. Then, copy over the partial string that precedes it. Skip the bad string in the input. Then, copy over the "good" string to the output.

Your capitalization function makes no sense [and appears to do nothing].

Also, converting the "black cat" string, from your example isn't general because it would need to special case "cat" to produce "Cat". For English, "cat" is *not* a proper name, so it should be all lowercase.

---

Unfortunately, your code needed some heavy refactoring in order to work.

I had to change the capitalization function to just capitalize the first char of the first word of each sentence as that was the only thing that made sense to me [adjust to suit your needs].

I wired in your two test cases. And, I've added some debug `printf` statements.

Anyway, here's the code. I've annotated it, so that the part you had an issue with [the word substitution] should give you some ideas.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//This function converts a string to a sentence.
void
StrtoSent(char *string)
{
    int length = 0,n = 0;
    length = strlen(string);
    for(n = 0;  n < length;  n++){
        if((n ==0) && (string[n] >= 'b' && string[n] <= 'y')){
            string[n] = string[n] - 32;
        }
        else if(string[n] == '.'){
            if(string[n + 1] == ' '){
                if(string[n+2]>= 'b' && string[n+2]<= 'y'){
                    string[n+2]= string[n+1] - 32;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// fixcap -- capitalize sentences in the string
void
fixcap(char *string)
{
    int capflg = 1;

    while (1) {
        int chr = *string;

        // end of string
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        switch (chr) {
        case ' ':
            break;

        case '.':  // end of sentence -- restart capitalization
        case '!':
            capflg = 1;
            break;

        default:
            // capitalize the [first letter of the] first word of a sentence
            if (capflg) {
                chr = toupper((unsigned char) chr);
                capflg = 0;
            }
            else
                chr = tolower((unsigned char) chr);
            break;
        }

        *string++ = chr;
    }
}

// fixword -- substitute word in string
void
fixword(char *out,const char *inp,const char *bad,const char *good)
{
    int lenbad = strlen(bad);
    int lengood = strlen(good);
    char *cp;
    int lencpy;

    while (1) {
        // find the "bad" string in the input
        cp = strcasestr(inp,bad);

        // the remaining input string is good -- copy it
        if (cp == NULL) {
            strcpy(out,inp);
            break;
        }

        // get the length of the string leading up to the "bad" string
        // copy it over and advance the pointers
        lencpy = cp - inp;
        memcpy(out,inp,lencpy);
        inp += lencpy;
        out += lencpy;

        // skip over the bad string in the input
        inp += lenbad;

        // copy over the "good" string and advance the output pointer
        strcpy(out,good);
        out += lengood;
    }
}

// fixall -- perform all actions
void
fixall(const char *string)
{
    char inp[1000];
    char out[1000];

    strcpy(inp,string);
    printf("DEBUG: BEFORE '%s'\n",inp);

    //Here,we send the string off to the function
#if 0
    StrtoSent(inp);
    printf("DEBUG: AFTCAP '%s'\n",inp);
#endif
#if 1
    fixcap(inp);
    printf("DEBUG: AFTCAP '%s'\n",inp);
#endif

    fixword(out,inp,"xirtaM","Matrix");
    printf("DEBUG: AFTFIX '%s'\n",out);
}

// doline -- read and process an input line
int
doline(void)
{
    char *cp;
    char string[1000];
    int more;

    do {
        printf("\n\nEnter a wordstring Neo: ");
        cp = fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);

        more = (cp != NULL);
        if (! more)
            break;

        // strip newline
        cp = strchr(string,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        fixall(string);
    } while (0);

    return more;
}

int
main(void)
{
#if 0
    char string[50] = {0};
    int length = 0,n = 0,a = 0,d = 0;
#endif

    // default test cases
    fixall("The xirtaM is acutally the Matrix!");
    fixall("a blACk cAT is in the xirtaM.");

    // read input lines and do conversions
    while (1) {
        if (! doline())
            break;
    }

#if 0
    char str[] = "The xirtaM is acutally the Matrix!";
    char j[] = "xirtaM";
    char e[] = "Matrix";
    char *result = NULL;
    printf("Original string: %s\n",str);
    printf("The converted sentence: %s",string);
    char input[200];
    getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(input,200,stdin);
    char c;
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        int n = c - '0'; //'0'-'9' -> 0 - 9
        printf("%c is coverted to %d\n",c,n);
    }
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        if(islower(c))
            printf("%c will be converted to %c\n",c,toupper(c));
        if(isupper(c))
            printf("%c in lowercase is %c\n",c,tolower(c));
        getchar();
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output for the default test cases:

```
DEBUG: BEFORE 'The xirtaM is acutally the Matrix!'
DEBUG: AFTCAP 'The xirtam is acutally the matrix!'
DEBUG: AFTFIX 'The Matrix is acutally the matrix!'
DEBUG: BEFORE 'a blACk cAT is in the xirtaM.'
DEBUG: AFTCAP 'A black cat is in the xirtam.'
DEBUG: AFTFIX 'A black cat is in the Matrix.'
```